# Why am I still able to execute a function despite getting the warning no privileges could be revoked

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I am trying to revoke a function from a `readonly_role` I have created

`REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_advisory_lock(integer, integer) FROM readonly_role;`

But I get this warning:

`WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "pg_advisory_lock"`

However, I am clearly still able to execute this function as the `readonly_role`:

```
select pg_advisory_lock(1,1);
 pg_advisory_lock 
------------------
 
(1 row)
```

What is happening here? Why can I not revoke this function and why am I still able to execute it with no privileges?

EDIT: Here is the privileges when I run `\df+ pg_advisory_lock();`

Note: the owner is `rdsadmin` which is owned by AWS. I cannot authenticate as `rdsadmin` I believe

```
Schema              | pg_catalog
Name                | pg_advisory_lock
Result data type    | void
Argument data types | integer, integer
Type                | func
Volatility          | volatile
Parallel            | restricted
Owner               | rdsadmin
Security            | invoker
Access privileges   | =X/rdsadmin                   +
                    | rdsadmin=X/rdsadmin
Language            | internal
Source code         | pg_advisory_lock_int4
Description         | obtain exclusive advisory lock
```

Worth noting that this is on Postgres 14.7 and being run on AWS RDS

Comment: As a guess, perhaps the permissions you're trying to remove aren't assigned at that level. E.g. perhaps you have execute permissions on the entire DB.

Comment: @Rogue - ahh you might be right. Would I then have to revoke it on the entire DB and then grant it for the users that might need it?

Comment: That would be my approach, yes. For this kind of fine grained permissions I'd be looking at assigning for a group over any one particular user, though (so I don't have to do it again).

Comment: @Rogue trying to do this `REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_advisory_lock(integer, integer) from PUBLIC;` but still getting the same warning... so now I'm not sure. Is that the correct statement to remove from the entire DB?

Comment: Note the [grammar for `REVOKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html): you'd be revoking `ON DATABASE`, not `ON FUNCTION`. There's a lot of places you can place permissions on, you should check the different items that could apply.

Comment: @Rogue, there are no `EXECUTE` privileges on a database. See [Privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html).

Comment: 1) You did not revoke any privileges `no privileges could be revoked for "pg_advisory_lock"`. 2) What role where you when you tried the `REVOKE`? `pg_advisory_lock` is system function, you need to be a superuser to manage privileges on it.

Comment: What privileges are there on the function at all? Please show what `\df+ pg_advisory_lock(integer, integer)` outputs in `psql`

Comment: What version are you using?  I can't reproduce either aspect of this.  After revoking from both the role itself and from PUBLIC, then execution is denied.  Also, no warning is issued.  Can you provide  fully reproducible test case, starting by creating the role?  Also, what role are you doing all of this as?

Comment: @Bergi I have edited the post to show the privileges when running `\df+ pg_advisory_lock(integer, integer)`

Comment: @jjanes here is the version `PostgreSQL 14.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` Also note this is being run on an AWS RDS client, so maybe that is why this is acting so weird..

I am doing this from a role I created called `readonly_role` which maybe is the problem. I am not able to log `rdsadmin` since that is AWS' user.. is there a way to authenticate as the admin here?

Comment: Yes that is the problem, the user you are issuing the `REVOKE` as does not have sufficient privileges to carry the command out. An per [AWS Permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Roles.html) you cannot log in as `rdsadmin`, that is an internal RDS role.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I figured... so is there anything that can be done to REVOKE this function or am I out of luck here?

Comment: This is under the control of AWS, you can't  change it. The 'benefits' of a managed product. The only thing you can do is change to a EC2 instance and install Postgres, then you would be the  superuser and could do what  you want.