# How to remove access of tables in pg_catalog for a user?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, superuser, pg-catalog

I am trying to create a view for the prod table for a client where he must only
have access to views.

I was able to restrict the user to have access to views and not to the table. But in postgres there is a concept of system catalog, where there are some metadata stored which I don't want to give access to the user.

I found the command to restrict pg_catalog tables by `REVOKE select ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA pg_catalog FROM PUBLIC;`

My our DB is in AWS RDS and I cant run this query, as the user must be superuser to run this.

I have tried below as well, but they did not work.
`REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA pg_catalog FROM user;`

`REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES on table pg_roles FROM PUBLIC;`

Comment: Read my comments here [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76908068/why-am-i-still-able-to-execute-a-function-despite-getting-the-warning-no-privile#comment135593107_76908068). AWS/RDS does not give you the privileges to do this. In other words this is not possible.